# Error when uploading into firebase database, unauthorized request

Tags: python, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently developing my App and I am uploading many information on my firebase database. My algorithm automatically write into my firebase database and sometimes , after like 2,000 writting (sometimes less sometimes more), I've this error. I'm aware that it might be linked to the auth rules but i don't know 
what to do.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "top1000.py", line 168, in <module>
    db.child("Artistes")....:""})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 301, in set
    raise_detailed_error(request_object)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 448, in raise_detailed_error
    raise HTTPError(e, request_object.text)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://silent-fuze-...] {
  "error" : "Unauthorized request."
}
```

I want to write into my database as an admin. Here is the code in my main algorithm.

```
config = {
    "apiKey": "...",
    "authDomain": "...",
    "databaseURL": "...",
    "projectId": "...",
    "storageBucket": "...",
    "messagingSenderId": "...",
    "serviceAccount": "clef.json"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()
```

And here is the one into my firebase rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}
```

It allows full read and write access to **authenticated users** of your app.
It means that if an user is not authenticated, he can't access the data and it is the reason of your error.
**You are trying to access without authentication.**

You can use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) to have users to sign in to your app

More info about security [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Comment: But don't I get authentificate by using API key , the database url inside my "config" ?

Comment: @FlorianBirolleau when the client try to read and write data, you have to authenticate the request since you have ask for it in your rules. The API KEY is not the key to authenticate an user, but just to config your project

Comment: Alright, but you said i need to configure users to sign into my app. My UI developer will take about that. For now i just need to authentificate myself in order to write into my database. What do i have to type into my code ?

Comment: You can authenticate with a test user/password (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth), or just set the rules to grant public access in your dev enviroment. (    ".read": true,  ".write": true)

Comment: When I set those rules ( ".read": true, ".write": true), i still have the same error ...

Comment: I feel like you didn't really get my problem. My work is to implement my database. My code is automatically getting some data from the web and writting it into firebase. my algorithm is writting let's say 2 data every seconds. And then my users will connect in order to read those data. That's what you were thinking of ? Thanks very much in advance :)

Comment: In my case the app worked in debug but after creating the standlaone executalble with PyInstaller it failed, I realized the Project Tree path was wrong, so  I corrected that and now it works alright. Also ensure that private-key.json is in the same path.